# Pythons TexSoup not parsing document

Tags: python, latex

I am using the Python module [TexSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup) to parse a `*.tex` file. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work at all. It parses the file successfully but the examples never return an expected value. For demonstration purposes I use this Python example called [solution_length.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvinwan/TexSoup/master/examples/solution_length.py)

```
from TexSoup import TexSoup

tex = """\\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \\begin{document}
    \\begin{equation} 
    1 + 1
    \\end{equation}
    \\end{document} 
"""
a = sum(len(a.string) for a in TexSoup(tex).find_all("\\begin{equation}"))
print(a)
```

returns

```
0
```

It looks the project still gets maintained but I can't make it work. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make this work is

```
from TexSoup import TexSoup

tex = r"""
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    1 + 1
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
"""
a = TexSoup(tex).count('equation')
print(a)
```

yielding

```
1
```

as expected.

Note that you need to correctly handle the backslashes in the tex source, so a raw string is easiest.  `count` is exactly designed to count instances, but the instances are not substrings of the document, but parsed constructs.  `find_all` returns instead an iterator over soup nodes:

```
b = TexSoup(tex).find_all('equation')
for i in b:
    print(type(i))
```

gives

```
<class 'TexSoup.data.TexNode'>
```

and its contents are obtained with `all`

```
for i in b:
    for x in i.all:
        print(x)
```

giving

```
    1 + 1
```

Comment: uh, I forgot about the backslashes :-( It seems the example is wrong. thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Swann Strange, I reused your code but I don't get the same result :/

```
for i in b:
    for x in i.all:
        print(x)
``
does not give `1+1`

Comment: @JeT I have just run the code again (python 3.9, TexSoup 0.3.1) and I get the output posted.  What output do you get?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Merci. I upgraded my python installation and It works fine now. 
I am new to python and TeXSoup seems to be what I need for  [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572445/turn-question-and-choices-of-exam-class-to-csv-with-a-python-perl-script). But struggling with the TeXSoup documentation :/